# Combine point cloud shader and terrain blending shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I am trying to combine two shaders for my point cloud mesh.
1st shader is a geometry shader which has 1 texture and a way to control the point size.

2nd shader blends multiple textures based on the height of point in the mesh.
I am very very new to shader coding and would like to combine the two.

If i literally copy paste them both into one file, then blending does not work. I would like to blend the textures and control the point cloud size.

I am very lost and would really appreciate any help.

1st Shader

```
Shader "Custom/TerrainShaderAll"{
Properties{
    _DeepWater("DeepWater", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ShallowWater("ShallowWater", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Sand("Sand", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Grass("Grass", 2D) = "white"{}
    _Tree("Tree", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Rock("Rock", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Snow("Snow", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e1("e1", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e2("e2", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e3("e3", 2D) = "white" {}
    _WaterLevel("Water Level", Float) = 0
    _LayerSize("LayerSize", Float) = 20
    _BlendRange("BlendRange", Range(0,1.5)) = 0.1
}
    Subshader{
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _DeepWater;
            uniform sampler2D _ShallowWater;
            uniform sampler2D _Sand;
            uniform sampler2D _Grass;
            uniform sampler2D _Tree;
            uniform sampler2D _Rock;
            uniform sampler2D _Snow;
            uniform sampler2D _e1;
            uniform sampler2D _e2;
            uniform sampler2D _e3;


            uniform float _WaterLevel;
            uniform float _LayerSize;
            uniform float _BlendRange;

            struct fragmentInput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 blend: COLOR;
            };

            fragmentInput vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                float NumOfTextures = 10;
                fragmentInput o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.texcoord = v.texcoord;

                float MinValue = _WaterLevel - (NumOfTextures - 1) * _LayerSize;
                float MaxValue = (_WaterLevel + _LayerSize);
                float Blend = MaxValue - v.vertex.z;
                Blend = clamp(Blend / (NumOfTextures * _LayerSize), 0, 1);

                o.blend.xyz = 0;
                o.blend.w = Blend;
                return o;
            }


            inline float CalculateBlend(float TextureFloat)
            {
                return 1 - clamp((1 - TextureFloat) / _BlendRange, 0, 1);
            }

            inline float4 DoBlending(float TextureID, float TextureFloat, fixed4 BaseTexture, fixed4 BlendTexture)
            {
                float Blend = CalculateBlend(clamp(TextureFloat - TextureID, 0, 1));
                return lerp(BaseTexture, BlendTexture, Blend);
            }

            float4 frag(fragmentInput i) : COLOR0
            {
                float NumOfTextures = 10;
                float TextureFloat = i.blend.w * NumOfTextures;

                if (TextureFloat < 1)
                {
                    fixed4 DeepWaterColor = tex2D(_DeepWater, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(0, TextureFloat, DeepWaterColor, ShallowWaterColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 2)
                {
                    fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 SandColor = tex2D(_Sand, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(1, TextureFloat, ShallowWaterColor, SandColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 3)
                {
                    fixed4 SandColor = tex2D(_Sand, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 GrassColor = tex2D(_Grass, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(2, TextureFloat, SandColor, GrassColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 4)
                {
                    fixed4 GrassColor = tex2D(_Grass, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 TreeColor = tex2D(_Tree, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(3, TextureFloat, GrassColor, TreeColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 5)
                {
                    fixed4 TreeColor = tex2D(_Tree, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 RockColor = tex2D(_Rock, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(4, TextureFloat, TreeColor, RockColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 6)
                {
                    fixed4 RockColor = tex2D(_Rock, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 SnowColor = tex2D(_Snow, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(5, TextureFloat, RockColor, SnowColor);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 7)
                {
                    fixed4 SnowColor = tex2D(_Snow, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 e1Color = tex2D(_e1, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(6, TextureFloat, SnowColor, e1Color);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 8)
                {
                    fixed4 e1Color = tex2D(_e1, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 e2Color = tex2D(_e2, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(7, TextureFloat, e1Color, e2Color);
                }
                if (TextureFloat < 9)
                {
                    fixed4 e2Color = tex2D(_e2, i.texcoord);
                    fixed4 e3Color = tex2D(_e3, i.texcoord);

                    return DoBlending(8, TextureFloat, e2Color, e3Color);
                }

                fixed4 e3Color = tex2D(_e3, i.texcoord);

                return e3Color;

                fixed4 DeepWaterColor = tex2D(_DeepWater, i.texcoord);
                fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.texcoord);

                return lerp(DeepWaterColor, ShallowWaterColor, i.blend.w);

            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

2nd Shader

```
Shader "Custom/PointCloudGeom" {
Properties {
    [NoScaleOffset]_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset]_UVMap ("UV", 2D) = "white" {}
    _PointSize("Point Size", Float) = 4.0
    _Color ("PointCloud Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    [Toggle(USE_DISTANCE)]_UseDistance ("Scale by distance?", float) = 0
}

SubShader
{
    Cull Off
    Pass 
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma geometry geom
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma shader_feature USE_DISTANCE
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        float _PointSize;
        fixed4 _Color;

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

        sampler2D _UVMap;
        float4 _UVMap_TexelSize;


        struct g2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        [maxvertexcount(4)]
        void geom(point v2f i[1], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream)
        {
            g2f o;
            float4 v = i[0].vertex;
            v.y = -v.y;

            // TODO: interpolate uvs on quad
            float2 uv = i[0].uv;
            float2 p = _PointSize * 0.001;
            p.y *= _ScreenParams.x / _ScreenParams.y;

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, -p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, -p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, -p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, -p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

        }
        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = v.vertex;
            o.uv = v.uv;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (g2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            float2 uv = tex2D(_UVMap, i.uv);
            if(any(uv <= 0 || uv >= 1))
                discard;
            // offset to pixel center
            uv += 0.5 * _MainTex_TexelSize.xy;
            return tex2D(_MainTex, uv) * _Color;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Comment: *`If i literally copy paste them both into one file`* Yeah, that's not how programming works. Each shader has a `vert` function and a `frag` function. You need to combine the math in these to do what you want at each *vert*ex and each pixel. The second shader also has a geom function, but the first doesn't. Good luck.

Comment: I wish it did. 
So `vert` controls position and `frag` controls color? would I be correct in saying that? and I cannot have two verts and frags blocks in the same shader file? or is there an execution order?

Comment: Not really no. If anything controls position, its `geom`. `vert` is more for vertex color (where complex color calculations are done once per vertex, then each pixel is computed based on effective its barycenter and the 3 verts). Recommended reading: [one](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/gentle-introduction-shaders?playlist=17102) [two](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Shaders.html)

Comment: `geom` controls position, `vert` and `frag` control color. and can target SV_Target or Color0 or Color1?
color(`texture`) is what im after.

Comment: `Recommended reading: one two` 
great suggestions thank you

Comment: All of those (SV_Target, Color0, Color1) are keywords with special meaning (and at the same time, in the context of your question, have no meaning at all). They're just a flag that tells the GPU (well, OpenGL or DirectX) that "this thing is used as a color." Getting and returning a color from a texture is trivial in comparison to what your shaders are currently doing (look at the usage of `tex2D`)

Comment: thanks for the input. I guess i can use color 0 with geom shader to blend then right?

Comment: I don't know. Combining shaders this complex is difficult, even if you know what you're doing. I have a very broad understanding of *how* to write shaders, but that doesn't mean I can do what you're asking. If you mean "should I use `Color0` or `SV_Target` on my frag function?" I will just shrug. As far as I can tell, they mean the same thing, but one is OpenGL-ish and the other is DirectX-ish.

Comment: link to some resource that does 2 texture blending in a geom shader would be really helpful. i see that 1st one is returning the maintex with refeerence to uv * the color and the other just returns the color instead and that is where the conflict it, since when i do combine it all of it works apart from the blending.

Comment: thanks for the guidance. i will post an answer if i get it working before someone else here. cheers!

Comment: @AnuragTiwari Did you try my answer or find a different solution to this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The point cloud shader doesn't do much in the frag and vert functions. So, I thought maybe it would work to take out the frag and the vert code from the blending shader and putting it into the point cloud shader:

```
Shader "Custom/PointCloudTerrain" {
Properties {
    _DeepWater("DeepWater", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ShallowWater("ShallowWater", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Sand("Sand", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Grass("Grass", 2D) = "white"{}
    _Tree("Tree", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Rock("Rock", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Snow("Snow", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e1("e1", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e2("e2", 2D) = "white" {}
    _e3("e3", 2D) = "white" {}
    _WaterLevel("Water Level", Float) = 0
    _LayerSize("LayerSize", Float) = 20
    _BlendRange("BlendRange", Range(0,1.5)) = 0.1


    [NoScaleOffset]_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    [NoScaleOffset]_UVMap ("UV", 2D) = "white" {}
    _PointSize("Point Size", Float) = 4.0
    _Color ("PointCloud Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    [Toggle(USE_DISTANCE)]_UseDistance ("Scale by distance?", float) = 0
}

SubShader
{
    Cull Off
    Pass 
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma geometry geom
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma shader_feature USE_DISTANCE
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {

            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 blend: COLOR;

        };

            uniform sampler2D _DeepWater;
            uniform sampler2D _ShallowWater;
            uniform sampler2D _Sand;
            uniform sampler2D _Grass;
            uniform sampler2D _Tree;
            uniform sampler2D _Rock;
            uniform sampler2D _Snow;
            uniform sampler2D _e1;
            uniform sampler2D _e2;
            uniform sampler2D _e3;


            uniform float _WaterLevel;
            uniform float _LayerSize;
            uniform float _BlendRange;


        float _PointSize;
        fixed4 _Color;

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

        sampler2D _UVMap;
        float4 _UVMap_TexelSize;


        struct g2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 blend: COLOR;
        };

        [maxvertexcount(4)]
        void geom(point v2f i[1], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream)
        {
            g2f o;
            float4 v = i[0].vertex;
            v.y = -v.y;

            // TODO: interpolate uvs on quad
            float2 uv = i[0].uv;
            float2 p = _PointSize * 0.001;
            p.y *= _ScreenParams.x / _ScreenParams.y;

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, -p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(-p.x, -p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v);
            #ifdef USE_DISTANCE
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, -p.y, 0, 0);
            #else
            o.vertex += float4(p.x, -p.y, 0, 0) * o.vertex.w;
            #endif
            o.uv = uv;
            triStream.Append(o);

        }

        inline float CalculateBlend(float TextureFloat)
        {
            return 1 - clamp((1 - TextureFloat) / _BlendRange, 0, 1);
        }

        inline float4 DoBlending(float TextureID, float TextureFloat, fixed4 BaseTexture, fixed4 BlendTexture)
        {
            float Blend = CalculateBlend(clamp(TextureFloat - TextureID, 0, 1));
            return lerp(BaseTexture, BlendTexture, Blend);
        }

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
                float NumOfTextures = 10;
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.texcoord;

                float MinValue = _WaterLevel - (NumOfTextures - 1) * _LayerSize;
                float MaxValue = (_WaterLevel + _LayerSize);
                float Blend = MaxValue - v.vertex.z;
                Blend = clamp(Blend / (NumOfTextures * _LayerSize), 0, 1);

                o.blend.xyz = 0;
                o.blend.w = Blend;
                return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (g2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            float NumOfTextures = 10;
            float TextureFloat = i.blend.w * NumOfTextures;

            if (TextureFloat < 1)
            {
                fixed4 DeepWaterColor = tex2D(_DeepWater, i.uv);
                fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(0, TextureFloat, DeepWaterColor, ShallowWaterColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 2)
            {
                fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.uv);
                fixed4 SandColor = tex2D(_Sand, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(1, TextureFloat, ShallowWaterColor, SandColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 3)
            {
                fixed4 SandColor = tex2D(_Sand, i.uv);
                fixed4 GrassColor = tex2D(_Grass, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(2, TextureFloat, SandColor, GrassColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 4)
            {
                fixed4 GrassColor = tex2D(_Grass, i.uv);
                fixed4 TreeColor = tex2D(_Tree, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(3, TextureFloat, GrassColor, TreeColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 5)
            {
                fixed4 TreeColor = tex2D(_Tree, i.uv);
                fixed4 RockColor = tex2D(_Rock, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(4, TextureFloat, TreeColor, RockColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 6)
            {
                fixed4 RockColor = tex2D(_Rock, i.uv);
                fixed4 SnowColor = tex2D(_Snow, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(5, TextureFloat, RockColor, SnowColor);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 7)
            {
                fixed4 SnowColor = tex2D(_Snow, i.uv);
                fixed4 e1Color = tex2D(_e1, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(6, TextureFloat, SnowColor, e1Color);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 8)
            {
                fixed4 e1Color = tex2D(_e1, i.uv);
                fixed4 e2Color = tex2D(_e2, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(7, TextureFloat, e1Color, e2Color);
            }
            if (TextureFloat < 9)
            {
                fixed4 e2Color = tex2D(_e2, i.uv);
                fixed4 e3Color = tex2D(_e3, i.uv);

                return DoBlending(8, TextureFloat, e2Color, e3Color);
            }

            fixed4 e3Color = tex2D(_e3, i.uv);

            return e3Color;

            fixed4 DeepWaterColor = tex2D(_DeepWater, i.uv);
            fixed4 ShallowWaterColor = tex2D(_ShallowWater, i.uv);

            return lerp(DeepWaterColor, ShallowWaterColor, i.blend.w);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

I can't test this right now so there are probably some copy & paste errors, especially in having to rename & add members to the `v2f`/`g2f` structs.  Let me know of any errors in the comments.